# Where do I post a question on issues creating Google wallet merchant account?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

As a developer, who wants to monetize his Android app, I have an issue opening a merchant account.

On what SE site should I open a question about the issue I'm having?

Comment: You probably should ask Play Store support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is about how to implement the Google Wallet in the code, you could refer to Stack Overflow.

But if it is about creating the account, I'm having trouble finding the right site for you to make sure you would get the responses you need so in this case I would refer to Google's support site.